# does Griffon support command-line (no swing user interface) project

Tags: groovy, griffon

does Griffon support command-line project?

I don't want to show swing user interface

Answer (score 1):

Not at this point, no. Griffon requires an UI toolkit and relies on Swing as the default one. Efforts are being made to make sure the core of the framework remains UI toolkit agnostic, that way you can switch to a different toolkit in an easier manner. It would be possible to write a Charva based plugin for Griffon for example.

Comment: Update: I've been experimenting with Lanterna http://code.google.com/p/lanterna/ preliminary results are encouraging as demonstrated by this pic http://www.flickr.com/photos/22798066@N04/8949644030/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to have your griffon app have a "throwaway" view, and interact with the user via the command-line. As long as your machine has some sort of window environment, swing won't choke, and if you launch the app from the command line, you should still be able to access stdin and stdout.